# spark scala rdd/dataframe save filtered and rejected data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, etl

I have a file like this:

```
id,insert_date,name
====================
1,20170620,abc
2,20170620,xyz
1,20170621,pqr
3,20170624,huy
,20170624,stu
```

I need to filter out the records with null ids. Also if any id is repeating, I need to select the record with max(insert_date).

I am doing like this:

```
val myDF = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter",",")
  .schema(myschema)
  .load(mypath)
myDF.registerTempTable("myTable")
val myFilteredDF=sqlContext.sql("""SELECT id,max(insert_date),name 
                FROM myTable GROUP BY id,name""").filter("length(id) >0"
myFilteredDF.show()
```

I get result the way I wanted. However at the same time, I need to get the rejected/filtered records to another DataFrame/RDD, to write to rejected records file. What is the best solution here. I understand I can do the opposite of what I do to filter out, but that does not look like a better solution

Comment: @mtoto thanks for looking, unfortunately I don't have

Answer (score 2):

You could try `except`:

```
val otherDF = myDF.except(myFilteredDF)
```

Comment: Thank you mtoto, however except will not get all the rejected records, if we have two identical records, which are  filtered out by max/group by

Comment: if you have identical records, you should first deduplicate your data. Unless you like collecting redundancy in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

you can use exceptAll instead of except in the case when you wish to keep duplicate records as well.
Reference -
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).